# Calling SQL System function on DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ssis

I need to execute the sql server system function over DataTable.

DataTable has a string value e.g. "12345", in this i need a substring which is configured in Sql server table like SUBSTRING(,0,2).

I'm able to get the condition from DB table.
But how to apply this condition in DataTable?

Comment: Are you passing the Datatable back to SQL Server?

Comment: @RossBush - No, just applying logic on the data values

Comment: There is a String.Substring() function in c# that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving this.

1 - You can create a view that calls your function, ie:

```
Create View testView
As
Select
dbo.myFunction(parameter)
FROM dbo.TableName
```

2 - You can use C# Substring function as Ross mentioned in his comment:

```
DataTableString.Substring(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUBSTRING` function in the query that is used to populate the `DataTable`.  `SUBSTRING(0, 2)` was used in your question, I'm guessing you want the first two letters letters of the column?  `SUBSTRING` in SQL Server starts at 1, while this same function begins at 0 in C#.  You'll need to use `(Column, 1, 2)` in a SQL query to return the first two characters.

```
string connStr = @"YourConnectionString;";
string cmd = @"SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 1, 2) AS ColumnA from YourSchema.YourTable";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //create data adapter from string with SQL command and SQL Connection object
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);

    //populate DataTable
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```